# Nested stdext::hash_map iteration

Tags: c++, unordered-map

i have a Problem regarding UNORDERED_MAP

im using these two typedefs:

```
typedef UNORDERED_MAP<uint32, WorldSession*> SessionCharMap;
typedef UNORDERED_MAP<uint32, SessionCharMap > SessionMap;
```

which are using following define:

```
#  define UNORDERED_MAP stdext::hash_map
```

So basicly thats 1 container containing many containers of the other type SessionMap -*> SessionCharMap.

in following m_sessions is used:

```
SessionMap m_sessions;
```

Its used to assign a Sessionid several subids to handle them differently.
If the uint32 of SessionCharMap == NULL the Account is not yet fully logged in and has to choose a Character.  This works fine, till i want to deassign a logged in Session to a not fully logged in Session:

```
bool DeassignCharFromSession(uint32 acc, uint32 chr){

SessionMap::iterator itr2;
for (itr2 = m_sessions.begin(); itr2 != m_sessions.end(); itr2++){       
    if(itr2->first == acc){
        for (SessionCharMap::iterator itr = itr2->second.begin(); itr != itr2->second.end(); itr++){
            if( itr->first == chr &&
                itr->second){
                WorldSession* ses = itr->second;                                                                                                    
                itr2->second.erase(itr);
                m_sessions[acc][NULL] = ses;
                sLog.outDebug("############################################1 %d %d",itr2->first,itr->first);

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

return false;
}
```

This code seam to break my m_sessions variable because the iterration Loop running over it to update Sessions does not terminate anymore.
I want to mention that i already tried "itr2->second[NULL] = ses;"

```
void UpdateSessions( uint32 diff )
int i = 0;
for (SessionMap::iterator itr2 = m_sessions.begin(); itr2 != m_sessions.end(); ++itr2){      
    int j = 0;
    for(SessionCharMap::iterator itr = itr2->second.begin(); itr != itr2->second.end(); ++itr){
        //WorldSession * pSession = itr->second;
        debug_log("########################### 123 %d %d %d %d %d",itr2->first,itr->first, itr->second ? 1 : 0, i,j);
        j++;
        WorldSessionFilter updater(itr->second);

        if(!itr->second){
            debug_log("########################### 1231 %d %d",itr2->first,itr->first);
            //itr2->second.erase(itr);
        } else
        if(!itr->second->Update(updater))
        {
            debug_log("########################### 1233");
            RemoveQueuedSession(itr->second);                               
            debug_log("########################### 1234");
            itr2->second.erase(itr);
            debug_log("########################### 1235");
            delete itr->second;             
            debug_log("########################### 1236");
        }           
    }
    i++;
}
}
```

Following Debugoutput i get:

```
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ############################################1 1 1
 012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 1
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 2
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 3
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 4
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 5
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 6
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 7
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 8
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 9
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 10
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 11
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 12
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 13
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 14
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 15
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 16
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 1231 1 0
 2012-09-08 08:33:13 ########################### 123 1 0 0 0 17
```

The i and j counter is only for the debugoutput. You can see the j counter going up for the inner Container. But i have only 1 Session online. If i want to logout it results in j going up to ~400 reading random memory ;-).

I dont understand why the for-loop

```
for (SessionCharMap::iterator itr = itr2->second.begin(); itr != itr2->second.end(); itr++){...}
```

runs over its boundaries. Please tell me if you found the mistake i am out of ideas.

And another thing: the UpdateSession Routine works fine when logged in correctly(only one iteration per for-loop). The Error first occurs when logging out. Then the iterrator goes crazy. My guess is, that i misshandled the container in DeassignCharFromSession.

UPDATE with help of you guys:

Corrected UpdateSession

```
void UpdateSessions( uint32 diff ){
int i = 0;
for (SessionMap::iterator itr2 = m_sessions.begin(); itr2 != m_sessions.end(); ++itr2){      
    int j = 0;
    for(SessionCharMap::iterator itr = itr2->second.begin(); itr != itr2->second.end();){
        //WorldSession * pSession = itr->second;
        debug_log("########################### 123 %d %d %d %d %d",itr2->first,itr->first, itr->second ? 1 : 0, i,j);
        j++;
        WorldSessionFilter updater(itr->second);

        debug_log("########################### 123 %d %d %d",itr2->first,itr->first, itr->second ? 1 : 0);
        if(!itr->second){
            //this case should never occur!
            debug_log("########################### 1231 %d %d",itr2->first,itr->first);
            ++itr;
            //itr2->second.erase(itr);
        }else

        if(!itr->second->Update(updater))
        {
            debug_log("########################### 1233");
            RemoveQueuedSession(itr->second);                               
            debug_log("########################### 1234");
            delete itr->second;
            debug_log("########################### 1235");
            itr2->second.erase(itr++);
            debug_log("########################### 1236");
        } else {
            ++itr;
        }
    }
    i++;
}           
}
```

Corrected DeassignCharFromSession:

```
bool DeassignCharFromSession(uint32 acc, uint32 chr){
if(m_sessions[acc][chr]){
    sLog.outDebug("############################################1 %d %d",acc,chr);
    m_sessions[acc][NULL] = m_sessions[acc][chr];
    m_sessions[acc].erase(chr);
    sLog.outDebug("############################################2");
    return true;
}

debug_log("################################### UUU2");
return false;
}
```

But the Problem remains: The loop in UpdateSessions keeps iterating over the unordered_map. It happens 348 times and then ends with an Accessviolation.
And im still confused why

if(!itr->second){..}

triggers. since there should be only one valid session in the unordered_map.

Comment: why are you using 2 loops instead of the hash_map built in functions: m_sessions[acc][chr] in the first place.

Comment: ah nice will try, but that only works for the delete part, since i need to loop over all logged in sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use erase you are *invalidating the iterator*. So when you write

```
itr2->second.erase(itr);
```

in `UpdateSessions` you can no longer use `itr` as it no longer points to a member of your hash map. So both the next line `delete itr->second;` and crucially the loop iteration `++itr` are errors. The first problem is easily fixed, just switch the order of the delete and the erase

```
delete itr->second;
itr2->second.erase(itr);
```

The second problem is a little trickier, basically you have to rewrite your loop like this

```
for (SessionCharMap::iterator itr = itr2->second.begin(); itr != itr2->second.end(); )
{
    ...
    if (itr->second->Update(updater))
    {
        ++itr;
    }
    else
    {
        ...
        delete itr->second;
        itr2->second.erase(itr++);
    }
}
```

This way you increment the iterator *before* you call erase but because you use the post-increment operator erase still gets the previous value of the iterator.

Comment: thanks, i think that solved some of the Problem, still j is incremented 348 times, where it only should be 1x. Corrected code in question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem.
The iterrator in UpdateSessions (see below) becomes invalid due the delete in DeassignCharFromSession. 
solved it with a break. this will lead for some sessions to wait 2 cycles for update.

```
///- Then send an update signal to remaining ones   
debug_log("############################## OOOOO LOL");
int i = 0;
for (SessionMap::iterator itr2 = m_sessions.begin(); itr2 != m_sessions.end(); ++itr2){      
    int j = 0;
    SessionCharMap::iterator itr;
    for(itr = itr2->second.begin(); itr != itr2->second.end();){
        //WorldSession * pSession = itr->second;
        debug_log("########################### 123 %d %d %d %d %d",itr2->first,itr->first, itr->second ? 1 : 0, i,j);
        j++;
        WorldSessionFilter updater(itr->second);

        debug_log("########################### 123 %d %d %d",itr2->first,itr->first, itr->second ? 1 : 0);
        if(!itr->second){
            //this case should never occur! but it does cuz iterator becomes invalid cuz of delete
            debug_log("########################### 1231 %d %d",itr2->first,itr->first);
            ++itr;
            break;
            //itr2->second.erase(itr);
        }else

        if(!itr->second->Update(updater))
        {
            debug_log("########################### 1233");
            RemoveQueuedSession(itr->second);                               
            debug_log("########################### 1234");
            delete itr->second;
            debug_log("########################### 1235");
            itr2->second.erase(itr++);
            debug_log("########################### 1236");
        } else {
            ++itr;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```